# How to acquire unique object id in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Does emacs lisp have a function that provides a unique object identifier, such as e.g. a memory address? Python has `id()`, which returns an integer guaranteed to be unique among presently existing objects. What about elisp?

Comment: @NicolasDudebout: I guess it's used to index hash-tables, balanced trees, ...

Comment: It is quite difficult to define a _general_ unique object identifier in a language with garbage collection. Particularly, an object's memory address is not as good as it seems to be as a unique identifier. Actually, `id([1, 2]) == id([3, 4])` evaluates to `True` in the CPython REPL because `[1, 2]` is garbage-collected and `[3, 4]` happens to be allocated at the same address as `[1, 2]`.

Comment: Actually, the reason is not for indexing but for printing. So for example, printing two different symbols with the same name yields the same result, but if we could print a numeric object identifier, we'd be able to tell from the output whether two symbols referred to at different points in a program were in fact the same object.

Comment: Careful: In most lisps (including Elisp), symbols with the same name are `eq` to each other. If you mean that you want to print `(list 1)` and `(list 1)` differently from each other, I'm not sure whether it's possible in Emacs. I'm also struggling to see why you would care.

Comment: I don't think that's right. `(eq 'symbol-1 (make-symbol "symbol-1"))` yields `nil`. Certainly, seeing an object's numeric identifier could be helpful when dealing with uninterned symbols.

Comment: @nbtrap: Ah, yes. But that's because the second one isn't interned. See the documentation for `make-symbol` for more information. I checked what I claimed by trying `(intern "foo")`, which does do what I expected... Sorry - I forgot that Elisp has uninterned symbols at all.

Comment: @RupertSwarbrick: Yes, I know. Hence the utility of `id`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My whole point in asking the question was that I was looking for a way to distinguish between the printed representations of different symbols that have the same name. Thanks to the elisp manual, I've discovered the variable `print-gensym`, which, when non-`nil`, causes `#:` to be prepended to uninterned symbols printed. Moreover, if the same call to `print` prints the same uninterned symbol more than once, it will mark the first one with `#N=` and subsequent ones with `#N#. This is exactly the kind of functionality I was looking for. For example:

```
(setq print-gensym t)
  ==> t
(make-symbol "foo")
  ==> #:foo
(setq a (make-symbol "foo"))
  ==> #:foo
(cons a a)
  ==> (#1=#:foo . #1#)
(setq b (make-symbol "foo"))
  ==> #:foo
(cons a b)
  ==> (#:foo . #:foo)
```

The `#:` notation works for `read` as well:

```
(setq a '#:foo)
  ==> #:foo
(symbol-name a)
  ==> "foo"
```

Note the `'` on `'#:foo`--the `#:` notation is a symbol-literal. Without the `'`, the uninterned symbol is evaluated:

```
(symbol-name '#:foo)
  ==> "foo"
(symbol-name #:foo)
 ==> (void-variable #:foo)
```

Answer (score 7):

The only reason I know for wanting a function like `id()` is to compare objects, and ensure that they only compare equal if they are the same (as in, in the same memory location). In Lisps, this is done a bit differently from in Python:

In most lisps, including elisp, there are several different notions of equality. The most expensive, and weakest equivalence is `equal`. This is not what you want, since two lists (say) are equal if they have the same elements (tested recursively with `equal`). As such

```
(equal (list 1 2) (list 1 2)) => T
```

is true. At the other end of the spectrum is `eq`, which tests "identity" rather than equality:

```
(eq (list 1 2) (list 1 2)) => NIL
```

This is what you want, I think.

So, it seems that Python works by providing one equality test, and then a function that gives you a memory location for each object, which then can be compared as integers. In Elisp (and at least Common Lisp too), on the other hand, there is more than one meaning of "equality".

Note, there is also "eql", which lies somewhere between the two.

(EDIT: My original answer probably wasn't clear enough about why the distinction between `eq` and `equal` probably solves the problem the original poster was having)

Comment: Please could the person who down-voted this answer explain what's wrong with it? The only possible reason I can see to look for an `id()` equivalent is to compare objects with respect to it. My answer explains the way to do that in Emacs lisp.

Comment: I've just edited the answer: hopefully it makes it more clear why it addresses the OP's question.

Comment: I already know about elisp's `eq` and Python's `is`. The thing that's particular to Python's `is` is that it lets you print two different numeric representations of objects that have the same `repr`.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such feature in Emacs Lisp, as far as I know. If you only need equality, use `eq`, which performs a pointer comparison behind the scenes. 
If you need a printable unique identifier, use [`gensym`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Creating-Symbols.html#index-gensym-67) from the `cl` package.
If you need a unique identifier to serve as an index in a data structure, use `gensym` (or maintain your own unique id — `gensym` is simpler and less error-prone).

Some languages bake a unique id into every object, but this has a cost: either every object needs extra memory to store the id, or the id is derived from the address of the object, which precludes modifying the address. Python chooses to pay the cost, Emacs chooses not to.